# gulp.series() doesn't run tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-4

I can't figure out why `gulp.series()` is not firing in my callback function.

I'm trying to grab a string from a user input with `gulp-prompt` and invoke a build and deployment function with `gulp.series()`. My tasks within `gulp.series()` don't fire at all.

```
gulp.task('test', function(){
  const prompt = require('gulp-prompt');
  return gulp.src('test.js')
    .pipe(prompt.prompt({
        type: 'checkbox',
        name: 'env',
        message: 'which environment do you want to deploy to?',
        choices: ['qa','prod']
    },function(res){
      //console.dir(res.env);
        var env = res.env;
        console.log(env);
        console.log('hi');
        gulp.series('clean', 'patternlab:build', 'tag-version', deployWeb.bind(this, env), function(done){
          done();
        });
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Calling `gulp.series('task1', 'task2')` does **not** run `task1` and `task2`. All it does is return a new function. Only once you call **that** function are the tasks actually executed.

That means in your case you need to do the following:

```
var runTasks = gulp.series('clean', 'patternlab:build',
                           'tag-version', deployWeb.bind(this, env));
runTasks();
```

The whole `function(done){ done(); }` part that you had in your code doesn't really make much sense and isn't needed for `gulp.series()`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still trying to understand what done() does. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks for fixing my question!

Comment: Unfortunately gulp documentation does not explain this. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

[Sven Schoenung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5892036/sven-schoenung)'s answer is correct.

If you don't want to add a new variable, just make it a self-calling JS function like,

```
gulp.series('clean', 'patternlab:build', 'tag-version', deployWeb.bind(this, env))();
```