# How to repeatedly launch a task from another task in gulp 4

Tags: gulp, gulp-4

I recently upgraded to gulp 4 and I am trying to solve a long standing issue of with my export process.

In short I have 3 (or more) independent folders in my project. By independent I mean that they each have **their own bundle.js and global.css file**. I have setup a `target` variable in my gulpfile which is used to create all the paths gulp needs for that `target`.

In the current situation when I want to export my entire project I need to manually change the `target` variable in the gulpfile and then run the `export` task.

I need something that works like the following (as the `other_folders` array can change)

```
/*----------  Exports current target  ----------*/
gulp.task('export', gulp.series(to_prod,'export_files', 'export_scripts_and_styles', 'export_fonts', 'export_core'));

/*----------  Exports all targets  ----------*/
gulp.task('export_all', function(done){
    var needs_exporting = other_folders.concat("website");

    needs_exporting.forEach(function(export_this){
        target = export_this;
        set_paths();

        // Here it needs to fire the generic export task
        gulp.series('export');
    });

    done();
});
```

The problem is that I cannot seem to find a way to call a gulp task in the `forEach` loop. Is there a way to do this or do I need a workaround?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gulp.series() doesn't run tasks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902010/gulp-series-doesnt-run-tasks)

Comment: @SvenSchoenung This partially solved my issue however, it should only run the next "export" task after the first one is finished. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `gulp.series('export')` doesn't immediately start the `export` task. It just returns a function that you have to call in order to start the `export` task.

However calling the returned function doesn't start the `export` task immediately either. The function is asynchronous. Only later is the `export` task actually started.

The easiest way to run an asynchronous function for each element of a collection in series is to use the [`eachSeries()`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries) function that's provided by the [`async`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) package:

```
var async = require('async');

gulp.task('export_all', function(done){
    var needs_exporting = other_folders.concat("website");

    async.eachSeries(needs_exporting, function(export_this, cb) {
        target = export_this;
        set_paths();

        gulp.series('export')(cb);
    }, done);
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Also thank you for editing my question, still learning how to ask correctly.