# Gulp 'series' and 'parallel' does not signal async completion even though everything works fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

According to their documentation on [`series()`](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/series) and [`parallel()`](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/parallel) and their example, you only need to return a function call. However it doesn't work for me. This is my code:

```js
import gulp from "gulp";

export const test = () => {
    return gulp.parallel(
        async () => console.log("Async done"),
        cb => { console.log("cb done"); cb(); },
    )(); // Without function call () nothing is run
};

// package.json gulp version:
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

The above code works fine, I can see the tasks being completed in the output. However, there's always a warning at the end:

> The following tasks did not complete: test
> Did you forget to signal async completion?

[image]

I have tried:

- Do exactly like the example and return `gulp.parallel()` call **without** calling it. However in that case, nothing is executed and this answer helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39902796/653457
- Remove either the `async` method or the `cb` method (so only a single task is executed). The warning still exists.

Is this a gulp's bug or did I do something wrong? I am new to Node and gulp.

I am not sure if this is related to the issue but I cannot use this like most documentation and examples:

```
import gulp, { series, parallel } from "gulp";
```

> Named export 'parallel' not found. The requested module 'gulp' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.

---

Update: for some reason, adding `async` to the function helps, I assume because Gulp now works on the Promise returned instead (you don't even need to use `await` on the `parallel` result, and it's not a `Promise` anyway):

```
export const test = async () => { // add async
```

Update 2:

Thanks to Mark comment, this also works but I have to wrap everything in another `series`, and technically `test` is done **BEFORE** the final task completes:

```js
export const test = (cb) => {
    return gulp.series(
        gulp.parallel(
            async () => { await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000)); console.log("Async done") },
            cb => { console.log("cb done"); cb(); },
        ),
        async () => cb(), // This is done after test finish
    )();
}

// Output:
// ...
// [12:24:44] Finished 'test' after 1.01 s
// [12:24:44] Finished '<anonymous>' after 1.33 ms
```

Comment: What happens if you use this: `export const test = (cb) => {` ? And then probably just call `cb()` without the arrow function.

Comment: @Mark yes that would work too, check the Update 2 I just added. Just curious why it's happening